# Show the full httprequest header

Tags: apex

I'm making an http callout that's having an odd issue. I'm getting a response that's complaining about a header key.
I can put that key into a debug message by using getHeader(key)
How can I get it to display every key in the header?
There is no getHeader(); method and I want to show a final view of what the header looks like in a debug so I know how its format, what keys are in it, the key values and exactly what it's sending

Comment: You can't on the Salesforce side. You can probably see the request headers in full from the other end more easily. If your current endpoint is giving you problems, there are many post bin type endpoints out there.

Comment: How can I tell why someone down voted my question?

Comment: You can't. Most questions posted in good faith will receive some sort of comment explaining the vote, but it is not required, and not everyone who votes down feels compelled to explain their reasoning.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I've been down voted before but I believe they've come with a reason that was usuallyan acceptable reason and I fixed the issue they had with my question. In this one I feel like my quesion is legit and was just wondering why someone down voted it so I could improve it

Comment: Looking at a few of the 'First Questions' I'm starting to think ssalesforce stackexchange has a troll who likes to downvote everything. Unfortunatly there's at least one in every crowd

Answer (score 1):

The request you create is not necessarily the request you send. For example, `Content-Length` is automatically set when you make a `PUT`, `POST` or `PATCH` call, even if you don't calculate this manually. To see what is actually being received, consider using an echo server. For example, you can use [Postman Echo](https://postman-echo.com/) to send requests and get the full headers and body back. You can then debug this to the log file to see the full contents.